# "No value specified for parameter 1" ao executar PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou testando um `insert` aqui e o seguinte erro me aparece:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Dao

```java
package modelo;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    public class PessoaDao {
        public void insere(PessoaBean pessoa) throws SQLException{  

            // conectando
            Connection con = new ConexaoMysql().getConexao();

            // cria um preparedStatement
            String sql = "insert into exemplo" +
                    " (nome,numero,dataExemplo)" +
                    " values (?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            // executa
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();

            System.out.println("Gravado!");

            con.close();
        }
    }
```

Bean

```java
package modelo;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class PessoaBean {
    private int Idexemplo;
    private String nome;
    private float numero; 
    private Calendar dataExemplo;

    public int getIdexemplo() {
        return Idexemplo;
    }
    public void setIdexemplo(int idexemplo) {
        Idexemplo = idexemplo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public float getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(float numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    public Calendar getDataExemplo() {
        return dataExemplo;
    }
    public void setDataExemplo(Calendar dataExemplo) {
        this.dataExemplo = dataExemplo;
    }
}
```

Main

```java
package modelo;



import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection c = new ConexaoMysql().getConexao();
        System.out.println("Conexão aberta!");
        c.close();

         PessoaBean p = new PessoaBean();  

         PessoaDao dao = new PessoaDao();  

          p.setNome("José da Silva");  
          p.setNumero(1232); 
          p.setDataExemplo(Calendar.getInstance());  


          dao.insere(p);  


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste método:

```
public class PessoaDao {
    public void insere(PessoaBean pessoa) throws SQLException{  

        // conectando
        Connection con = new ConexaoMysql().getConexao();

        // cria um preparedStatement
        String sql = "insert into exemplo" +
                " (nome,numero,dataExemplo)" +
                " values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        // executa
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();

        System.out.println("Gravado!");

        con.close();
    }
}
```

Você se esqueceu de colocar isso:

```
stmt.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
stmt.setFloat(2, pessoa.getNumero());
stmt.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(pessoa.getDataExemplo().getTimeInMillis()));
```

Tem que colocar isso antes do `stmt.execute();`.

Além disso, é uma boa prática usar o *try-with-resources* para evitar que no caso de uma `SQLException`, você fique com recursos abertos. Desta forma, seu método fica assim:

```
public class PessoaDao {
    public void insere(PessoaBean pessoa) throws SQLException {

        // cria um preparedStatement
        String sql = "insert into exemplo" +
                " (nome,numero,dataExemplo)" +
                " values (?,?,?)";

        // conectando
        try (Connection con = new ConexaoMysql().getConexao();
             PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql))
        {

            stmt.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
            stmt.setFloat(2, pessoa.getNumero());
            stmt.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(pessoa.getDataExemplo().getTimeInMillis()));

            // executa
            stmt.execute();
        }

        System.out.println("Gravado!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nuss esqueci de setar ¬¬, mas blz cara valeu aí

Comment: @Jarwin Em questão de "respostas", apenas comente ao autor o possível problema. Edite apenas erros de português e marcação.

Comment: @Jarwin Desculpe, era para ser um ponto-e-vírgula, e não uma vírgula. Já arrumei.

Comment: Tranquilo cara  ;)

Answer (score 2):

É necessário informar os valores no insert, use o método set do prepared statement.

```
String sql = "insert into exemplo (nome,numero,dataExemplo) values (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString(1,  'valor1');
stmt.setString(2,  'valor2');
stmt.setString(3,  'valor3');
```

Comment: Obrigado cara ;)